# getCommState() failure error 87 in Code::Blocks IDE in WIN7 64 bits PC/Laptop

Tags: c++

My project is to open a serial port and receive strings data from ARM LPC1768 uController. I am facing problem with using getCommState() with error 87. I`m Using the followings :
1. Code::Blocks IDE (ver. 10.05 32 bit) with MinGW GCC compiler
2. GUI done in wxWidgets
3. Laptop having Win7 64 bits
4. USB-to-Serial Converter (in HyperTerminal, it shows COM10)

My program successfully opens the COM10 port, but getCommState() returns 0.

Can anyone help me ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In MSDN site, I found the solution.

By using **wxT("\\\.\\COM10")** as the 1st parameter in createFile(), I got the right kind of file handler and using the handler, I can now use getCommstate() and setCommState() with proper returns/no error.

Sorry for the post.